# QGIS: How to append one Geopackage layer into another Geopackage layer?

Tags: qgis, geopackage, append

At 3.8.3, I need to to append one Geopackage layer to another Geopackage layer, both in the same Geopackage.  Let’s say my Geopackage has two layers, A and B.  How do I append B into A?

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer.  First, make sure that both layers (source and target) have identical schemas.  In the Table of Contents, right-click the source layer (In my example, layer B) and *Export > Save Features As...*

Now, the *Save Vector Layer…* window appears.  Here, drop-down *Format* and select Geopackage.  Under *File name*, enter the Geopackage’s path and name.  Under *Layer name*, enter the target layer that you are appending to (in my case, this is “A”).  Make sure that the source and target layer CRSs are identical!  Under *Select fields to export and their export options*, uncheck FID (the append process will update the target layer's FID values).

You will then be notified that *The layer already exists*.  Here, click the *Append to Layer* button.

The *Select Vector Layers to Add…* window will appear.  Do not click any of the layers; simply click the *Ok* button.

Voila!  The source layer has been appended to the target layer.

EDIT:  If you have the target attribute table open when the append operation occurs, it does not appear to automatically update.  Thus, you'll have to close the table and re-open, which refreshes it, now displaying the appended records.